# How to obtain a value of a node in a XML file. Not working code

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a html code that is supposed to create a xmlDoc object, read an XML code into it from a file, get a value of a node and print it on screen. However, the code below is executed but does not read the value. What I get is just empty string I guess. I tried .firstChild and the result was the same:

```
<text> is :)
```

Between "<text> and "is :)" I'd expect "My child no 1.". Thanks for any help.

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test html</title>
    <script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("test_xml.xml");
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("child")[0].childNodes[0];
        var txt = x.nodeValue;
        document.write("&lt;txt&gt; is " + txt + "    :)");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

XML test_xml.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <children>
        <child id="1">
            <txt>My child no 1.</txt>
        </child>
        <child id="2">
            <txt>My child no 2.</txt>
        </child>
        <child id="3">
            <txt>My child no 3.</txt>
        </child>
        <child id="4">
            <txt>My child no 4.</txt>
        </child>
    </children>
</root>
```

and loadXMLDoc function in loadxmldoc.js file:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE5 and IE6
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

Comment: You you have a web server that provides the file or do you try to load the file directly from the local file system?

Comment: I have enabled a PHP/MySql server on my MacBookPro and all files are loaded from the server via a web browser. Also, all the files are on my local server.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the full answer to my question but the problem is partially resolved. The code below works but I've got to use `getElementsByTagName` function to get to html tags which I wanted to avoid and use `firstChild`, for instance. Anyway this is what works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test html</title>
    <script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("test_xml.xml");
        var children = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("children")[0];
        var childn = children.getElementsByTagName("child")[0];
        var x = childn.getElementsByTagName("txt")[0];
        document.write("&lt;txt&gt; is " + x.firstChild.nodeValue + " :)");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```